# Oculus doesn't render Gizmos Unity Android Build

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculusquest

I encountered issues while creating an Android build for the Oculus Quest 2. However, after updating the project to 2023 version of Unity and its settings, I managed to get the game running.

Currently, the game’s performance isn’t at it's best, but that's another day problem. The main issue I’ve noticed is the absence of the rayhandcasting gizmos. As evident from the video, the raycast is functioning, but the laser that should emit from the right hand isn’t visible in the build.

I tried to update the build and project settings to what Unity have recommended for Oculus Quest 2, but it didn't fix the problem.

Some pictures: https://imgur.com/a/xivjuM5

Comment: Unity gizmos only exist for debugging and for adding extra editing capabilities in the scene view - they don't get compiled or rendered in a real build of the game. If you want to render lines in-game, check out the `LineRenderer` component, or use a third party asset like Shapes

Comment: Ahh I see! Thank you for letting me know!